# Is Lagrangian a scalar?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, invariants

I may be wrong:

Lagrangian are scalars. They are NOT invariant under coordinate transformations. The simplest example is when you have a gravitational potential ($V=mgz$) and you translate $z$ by $a$ (some number). 
$$L=\frac12m\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2-mgz\to L=\frac12m\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2-mgz-mga$$ 
thus the Lagrangian changed under this coordinate transformation. However Euler-Lagrange equations ARE invariant under coordinate transformations. **So some scalars do vary under coordinate transformation!** Thus components of vectors are scalars, thus time is. Again, try to say the following sentence:

> the vector $a$ is the first component of the vector $b$.

Can you please clarify?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question ?

Comment: There aren't co-ordinate transformations but inertial frame transformations that change lagrangian and they do change scalar quantities like velocity.

Answer (score 9):

I assume to work in classical physics. Consider the space $M$ equipped with a Lagrangian local coordinate patch  $t, q^1,\ldots, q^n, \dot{q}^1,\ldots, \dot{q}^n$. Assume that the (smooth) Lagrangian of a given physical system takes the form, in that coordinate patch:
$${\cal L}= {\cal L}(t, q^1,\ldots, q^n, \dot{q}^1,\ldots, \dot{q}^n)\:.$$
Then **Euler-Lagrange** equations read, in that coordinate patch:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \dot{q}^k}= \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial q^k}\:, \qquad \frac{dq^k}{dt}= \dot{q}^k\:, \quad k=1,\ldots, n\:. \quad (1)$$

The second set of equations recalls that $\dot{q}^k$ and $q^k$ have to be considered as **independent variables**, while their natural relationship  holds just on the curves 
$$\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto (q^1(t),\ldots, q^n(t), \dot{q}^1(t),\ldots, \dot{q}^n(t))$$
describing the motion of the system.
What happens if *changing* Larangian coordinates,  passing to coordinates $T, Q^1,\ldots, Q^n, \dot{Q}^1,\ldots, \dot{Q}^n$ such that:
$$t=T+c\:,\quad q^k=q^k(T, Q^1,\ldots, Q^n)\:, \quad \dot{q}^k= \frac{\partial q^k}{\partial T}+ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial q^k}{\partial Q^j}{\dot Q}^j\:,\quad (2)$$
where $c\in \mathbb R$ is a constant, $k=1,2,\ldots ,n$, and the written transformation is supposed to be smooth with inverse (of the same type) smooth?

(The transformation $t=T+c$ simply states that, in classical physics, time is absolute and can be changed only redefining its origin). It is possible to prove the following theorem.

**THEOREM.** *If defining the new Lagrangian function in the coordinate patch equipped with coordinates  $T, Q^1,\ldots, Q^n, \dot{Q}^1,\ldots, \dot{Q}^n$:
$${\cal L}'(T,Q^1,\ldots, Q^n, \dot{Q}^1, \ldots, \dot{Q}^n) :=
{\cal L}(t, q^1,\ldots, q^n, \dot{q}^1,\ldots, \dot{q}^n)\:,\qquad (3)$$
where the new coordinates are related with the old ones via (2), then a smooth curve 
$$\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto (q^1(t),\ldots, q^n(t), \dot{q}^1(t),\ldots, \dot{q}^n(t))$$
satisfies (1) if and only if the corresponding (via the inverse of (2)) curve

$$\mathbb R \ni T \mapsto (Q^1(T),\ldots, Q^n(T), \dot{Q}^1(T),\ldots, \dot{Q}^n(T))$$
solves*
$$\frac{d}{dT} \frac{\partial {\cal L}'}{\partial \dot{Q}^k}= \frac{\partial {\cal L}'}{\partial Q^k}\:, \qquad \frac{dQ^k}{dT}= \dot{Q}^k\:, \quad k=1,\ldots, n\:. $$

In practice the theorem says that, *if we assume that $\cal L$ is a **scalar** (as written in (3))*, then the solutions of the dynamical equations do not depend on the used coordinates as requested by physics.

**REMARK.** This result is by no means obvious. For instance if you pass form the Lagrangian formulation to the Hamiltonian one, there is no analogous result:   The solutions of  dynamical equations do not depend on the used coordinates provided the Hamiltonian function has *not* scalar behaviour changing Hamiltonian coordinates $(t,q, p) \to (T,Q,P)$. (The problem arises only when time explicitly appears in the transformation of coordinates.)

The mentioned theorem permits us to choose Lagrangian coordinates and Lagrangian function independently. For example, consider a point of matter constrained to stay on a smooth surface $\Sigma$ at rest  with a non-inertial reference frame $I'$, whose motion is given with respect to an inertial reference frame $I$. It is clear that the equations simplify if describing the system using coordinates at rest with $I'$ (coordinates on $\Sigma$), since the equation of the surface containing the point does not depend on time in $I'$. However, in $I'$, inertial forces appear, and these have to be included in the Lagrangian giving rise to a complicated functional form. The stated theorem allows one to make an intermediate choice: writing the Lagrangian ${\cal L}|_I := K|_{I}-V|_{I}$  with respect to $I$, so that no inertial force has to be taken into account in $V|_I$, but using coordinates adapted to  $I'$. The discussion obviously applies also to the case of both $I$ and $I'$ inertial.

What you say in your question concerning the Lagrangian:

$${\cal L}=\frac12m\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2-mgz\to L=\frac12m\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2-mgz-mga$$ 
**has nothing to do with the fact that the Lagrangian is a scalar or not,** because you are considering **active** coordinate transformations instead of **passive** ones as due in discussing these issues. 
You have two coordinate systems $t,z, \dot{z}$ and $T,Z,\dot{Z}$ with 
$$T=t\:, \quad Z=z+h\;, \quad \dot{Z}= \dot{z}\:.\qquad (4)$$
Assuming that the Lagrangian is a scalar means nothing but that, if in coordinates $t,z,\dot{z}$:
$${\cal L}(t,z,\dot{z}) =\frac12m\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2-mgz\:,\qquad(5)$$
 the Lagrangian in coordinates $T,Z,\dot{Z}$ must verify:
$${\cal L}'(T,Z,\dot{Z})=\frac12m\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2-mgz$$
so that, exploiting (4):
$${\cal L}'(T,Z,\dot{Z})=\frac12m\left(\frac{dZ}{dT}\right)^2-mg(Z-h)$$
that has a *different* form from (5), but it does not matter!

What is physically (a bit) unexpected from your example is that the *form* of the Lagrangian changes changing reference frame, even if the two reference frames are completely *physically equivalent*. This is not a true problem, just in view of the stated theorem and the discussion following the  **REMARK** above: There are many **equivalent** Lagrangians for the same physical system. If in coordinates $T, Z, \dot{Z}$ you start form a Larangian with the same form of ${\cal L}$, I mean:
$${\cal L}'_1 = \frac12m\left(\frac{dZ}{dT}\right)^2-mgZ$$
you obtain the same equation of motion as those obtained from ${\cal L}'$, even if ${\cal L}'_1 \neq {\cal L}'$.

As a final remark, notice that, even if ${\cal L}'_1 \neq {\cal L}'$, the **action functionals** associated to these Lagrangians coincide. This suggests  another overall viewpoint on these issues, but I do not want to open another long discussion here.

Comment: Superb answer, but the PO didn't get it.